# How in gdi push, translate, rotate and pop state?

Tags: java, android, gdi

I am trying to draw circular menu with item presented as ar with 60 degree and image/icon inside. Problem is when I rotate menu, I have more than 3 items and menu is half of circle (180 degree), when I rotate I rotate items/arcs with images inside. Is possible here to do something similar to OpenGL, save state, psuh matrix, translate, rotate opposite and pop again ? I have marked line where is a problem. Does anyone know how to o this, (icon to be always vertical)

```
            float mSweep = 60;
            for (Integer key : mConversionPositionToID.keySet()) {

                String tempKey = mConversionPositionToID.get(key);
                SemiCircularRadialMenuItem item = mMenuItems.get(tempKey);
                mRadialMenuPaint.setColor(item.getBackgroundColor());
                item.setMenuPath(mMenuCenterButtonRect, mMenuRect, mStart,
                        mSweep, mRadius, mViewAnchorPoints);
                canvas.drawPath(item.getMenuPath(), mRadialMenuPaint);
                if (isShowMenuText) {
                    mRadialMenuPaint.setShadowLayer(mShadowRadius, 0.0f,
                            0.0f, Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    mRadialMenuPaint.setColor(item.getTextColor());
                    canvas.drawTextOnPath(item.getText(),
                            item.getMenuPath(), 5, textSize,
                            mRadialMenuPaint);
                    mRadialMenuPaint.setShadowLayer(mShadowRadius, 0.0f,
                            0.0f, mShadowColor);
                }

// HERE I have position of icon/image center
                item.getIcon().draw(canvas);
                mStart += mSweep;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a matrix object with that has attributes of the Menu?

Sample Code from the rotate method:

```
Status Rotate(
  [in]  REAL angle, // You can put your menu angle here
  [in]  MatrixOrder order
);
```